# Regex to "normalize" usage of SPACE after . , : chars (and some exceptions)

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I need to normalize some texts (product descriptions) in regard to the correct usage of `.`,`,`,`:` symbols *(no space before and one space after)*

The regex I've come up with is this:

`$variation['DESCRIPTION'] = preg_replace('#\s*([:,.])\s*(?!<br />)#', '$1 ', $variation['DESCRIPTION']);`

The problem is that this matches four cases it shouldn't touch:

- Any decimal number, like 5.5
- Any thousand separator, like 4,500
- A "fixed" phrase in Greek, `ό,τι`
- **The ellipsis symbol, `...`** - Basically ellipsis is a totally special case, that I'm thinking should be taken care of in a separate `preg_replace` maybe? I mean, the three dots should be treated as one thing, meaning that `some text ...` should indeed be matched and converted to `some text...` but not to `some text. . .`

Especially for the numeric exception, I know it can be achieved with some negative lookahead/lookbehind but unfortunately I can't combine them in my current pattern.

[This](https://regex101.com/r/8yddJI/1/) is a fiddle for you to check (the cases that shouldn't be matched are in lines 2, 3, 4).

EDIT: Both of the solutions posted below work fine, but end up adding a space after the last fullstop of the description. This is not much of a problem, as earlier in my code, I was taking care of the `<br />`s and *spaces* at the beginning and end of the description, so I moved this preg_replace before that one...

So, the final code I ended up using is this:

```
$variation['DESCRIPTION'] = preg_replace('#\s*([:,.])(?!(?<=\d.)\d)(?!(?<=ό,)τι)\s*#ui', '$1 ', $variation['DESCRIPTION']);
$variation['DESCRIPTION'] = preg_replace('#^\s*(<br />)*\s*|\s*(<br />)*\s*$#', '', $variation['DESCRIPTION']);
```

So the only thing that's left to achieve is alter this code so that it treats the ellipsis the way I describe above.

Any help with this last requirement will be very much appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add two lookaheads containing lookbehinds:

```php
\s*(\.{2,}|[:,.](?!(?<=ό,)τι)(?!(?<=\d.)\d))(?!\s*<br\s*/>)\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OFjWSI/7). Note that I also added `\s*` to the last lookahead and swapped it with the consuming `\s*` to fail the match if there is `<br/>` after any zero or more whitespaces after the `:`, `,` or `.`.

*Details*

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\.{2,}|[:,.])` - Group 1: two or more dots, or  a `:`, `,` or `.`
- **`(?!(?<=ό,)τι)` - fail the match if the next two chars are `τι` preceded with `ό,`**
- **`(?!(?<=\d.)\d)` - fail the match if the next char is a digit preceded with a digit and any char** (note that a `.` is enough since the `[:,.]` already match the char allowed/required, here, we just need to "jump" over that matched char)
- `(?!\s*<br\s*/>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitespaces, `<br`, zero or more whitespaces, `/>` immediately to the right of the current location.
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239256/discussion-on-answer-by-wiktor-stribizew-regex-to-normalize-usage-of-space-aft).

Answer (score 3):

If Wiktor's lookaround-heavy pattern is too difficult for you to conceptualize/maintain/adapt, then perhap a match&ignore technique will be easier for you. Admittedly, Wiktor's pattern is optimized for performance.

Pattern:

```
~                        #starting pattern delimiter 
\s*                      #zero or more whitespaces
(?:                      #start non-capturing group #1
  (?:                    #start non-capturing group #2
    \.\d+                #match float expression not requiring leading digits
    |                    #or
    \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+   #match number containing thousands separators
    |                    #or
    ό,τι                 #match literal greek phrase
    |                    #or
    <br\s*/>             #match html break tag
  )                      #end non-capturing group #2
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL)         #discard anything matched by group #2
  |                      #or
  (                      #start capture group #1
    \.{3}                #match three dots as ellipsis
    |                    #or
    [:,.]                #match literal colon, comma, or dot
  )                      #end capture group #1
)                        #end non-capturing group #1
\s*                      #zero or more whitespaces
~                        #ending pattern delimiter
```

As you wish to extend your pattern to include more disqualifying rules, just add another pipe and add a subpattern to match the unwanted substring.

To ensure that three qualifying dots are matched as an ellipsis, match this before checking for individual characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qE13t))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Composition:80% Polyamide,   15% Elastane, 5% Wool.
Side length 50.5 cm <---- THIS SHOULDN'T BE MATCHED
Value 4,500 <---- THIS SHOULDN'T BE MATCHED EITHER

What about $1,234,567.89?
Or....1mm one tenth of a millimeter?

ό,τι<---- THIS IS A FIXED PHRASE IN GREEK AND THEREFORE SHOULDN'T BE MATCHED
Comfort and timeless design characterize the Puma Smash V2 made of suede leather. They can be worn all the time ,being a unique choice for those who want to stand out .Made of rubber.<br />- Softfoam floor<br />- Binding with laces

Specs:<br />&bull; Something<br /><br />&bull; Something else<br />&bull; One more

Children's Form Champion<br /><br />Children's set that will give a comfortable feeling for endless hours of play.<br />It consists of a cardigan and trousers ,made of soft fabric and have rib cuffs and legs for a better fit.<br /><br />&bull; Normal fit<br /><br />&bull; Cardigan  :Rib cuffs, zippers throughout length, high neck, Champion logo <br /> <br />&bull; Pants: Elastic waist with drawstring, ribbed legs, Champion logo. Don't worry,there'll be ...more!
TEXT;

echo preg_replace(
         '~\s*(?:(?:\.\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|ό,τι|<br\s*/>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\.{3}|[:,.]))\s*~',
         '$1 ',
         $text
     );
```

Output:

```
Composition: 80% Polyamide, 15% Elastane, 5% Wool. Side length 50.5 cm <---- THIS SHOULDN'T BE MATCHED
Value 4,500 <---- THIS SHOULDN'T BE MATCHED EITHER

What about $1,234,567.89?
Or... .1mm one tenth of a millimeter?

ό,τι<---- THIS IS A FIXED PHRASE IN GREEK AND THEREFORE SHOULDN'T BE MATCHED
Comfort and timeless design characterize the Puma Smash V2 made of suede leather. They can be worn all the time, being a unique choice for those who want to stand out. Made of rubber. <br />- Softfoam floor<br />- Binding with laces

Specs: <br />&bull; Something<br /><br />&bull; Something else<br />&bull; One more

Children's Form Champion<br /><br />Children's set that will give a comfortable feeling for endless hours of play. <br />It consists of a cardigan and trousers, made of soft fabric and have rib cuffs and legs for a better fit. <br /><br />&bull; Normal fit<br /><br />&bull; Cardigan: Rib cuffs, zippers throughout length, high neck, Champion logo <br /> <br />&bull; Pants: Elastic waist with drawstring, ribbed legs, Champion logo. Don't worry, there'll be ...more!
```